# Two or more matches in expression

Tags: php, regex

Is it possible to make two matches of text - `/123/123/123?edit`

I need to match `123`, `123` ,`123` and `edit`

For the first(123,123,123): pattern is - `([^\/]+)`
For the second(edit): pattern is - `([^\?=]*$)`

Is it possible to match in one `preg_match_all` function, or I need to do it twice - one time for one pattern, second one for second?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) call:

```
$string = '/123/123/123?edit';
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('#(?<=[/?])\w+#', $string, $matches);

/* $matches will be:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 123
            [2] => 123
            [3] => edit
        )

)
*/
```

See this in action at http://www.ideone.com/eb2dy

The pattern (`(?<=[/?])\w+`) uses a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert that either a slash or a question mark must precede a sequence of word characters (`\w` is a [shorthand class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#shorthand) equivalent to `[a-z0-9_]`).